# Accessing array by pointer to an array in avr assembly

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, avr

I'm programming an AVR microcontroller using a mix of C and ASM but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I have the following code in my C code:

```
uint8_t amplitudes32[32] = {.. constant values ..};
uint8_t amplitudes64[64] = {.. constant values ..}
uint8_t* amplitudes;
```

(amplitudes32/64 are basically look up tables)

And some times I want amplitudes to be equal to amplitudes32 and sometimes want it to be equal to  amplitudes64.

I'm doing this by going

`amplitudes = amplitudes32;` in my c code.

Then, in my ASM interrupt routine I want to read in the address of the array like this:

```
ldi r30, lo8(amplitudes)    
ldi r31, hi8(amplitudes)
```

I then do some more instructions to get the value of the array at a certain index out to a particular port. However, when I check the output it's not working properly and I get something I'm not expecting. I get the same thing no matter what the array is made up of.. it's the same even when `amplitudes` is pointing to an array of all zeros.

If I change the assembly code to

```
ldi r30, lo8(amplitudes64)      
ldi r31, hi8(amplitudes64)
```

Then it works as expected. But like I said, I need to have a different look up table at different times and because of speed issues I can't make that decision within the interrupt routine so it'd be nice if I could have an array 'variable' that I could change in my C code which the interrupt then uses.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with AVR assembly.  However, I believe that the lo8 and hi8 macros are returning the low/high *address* of the supplied variable-- In the case of passing in amplitudes64, you'll fill out r30/r31 with the *address* of your 64 entry table-- exactly what you want.  However, if you pass in amplitudes, you are taking the *address of the pointer*, which is likely not what you want.  (The amplitudes variable would need to be dereferenced to get back to the original table.)

Since dereferencing variables is often comparatively slow in a microcontroller (especially within a time-sensitive interrupt), I strongly suggest that you reorganize your code to have a single boolean flag to select between the two tables.  For example:

```
if (UseTable64)
 ldi r30, lo8(amplitudes64)      
 ldi r31, hi8(amplitudes64) 
else
 ldi r30, lo8(amplitudes32)      
 ldi r31, hi8(amplitudes32) 
end if
```

The end result of this should be just one extra branch instruction-- likely faster than the extra time to dereference the amplitude pointer.  Alternatively, you could try merging both lookup tables into one 96 byte table, and just adjust your index accordingly.  As before, you can still perform the time consuming decision of which table to use *outside of the interrupt* (by modifying the flag within your C code), so as to allow the interrupt to remain fast and efficient.

Comment: Thank you! Very eloquent solution, wish I had thought of that myself. :)